# not able to locate the block various declaration

Tags: go-ethereum

I am not able to locate, the declaration of the following variables (Time, ParentHash, Extra, etc.) in go-ethereum. It is the part of the core/genesis.go program

> Variable:

```
            Time:       common.String2Big(genesis.Timestamp),
            ParentHash: common.HexToHash(genesis.ParentHash),
            Extra:      common.FromHex(genesis.ExtraData),
            GasLimit:   common.String2Big(genesis.GasLimit),
            Difficulty: difficulty,
            MixDigest:  common.HexToHash(genesis.Mixhash),
            Coinbase:   common.HexToAddress(genesis.Coinbase),
            Root:       root,
```

I found the declarations in core/types/block.go, but those declarations are not mapping with this. I wish to add additional parameter in the block. I would like to do it in private network.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a new variable to the block *header* - and it sounds like you do - then [block.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/block.go) is the place to start.

I'd start with the definition of [Header](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/block.go#L76) itself, then look at other places in that file that the new member will need to be added. (For example, the [JSON](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/block.go#L94) definition and associated functions [[1](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/block.go#L138), [2]](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/block.go#L159) .)

With regards to how these variables are set, if the variable is something that you want to be able to set in the genesis block of your private chain, then you'll also need to handle it in [genesis.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/genesis.go) (like you found). If the variable relates to something that is set *after* genesis, then you will need to decide how and where to do that - it will presumably depend on exactly what the function of the variable is.

Comment: thank you very much. I made the mistake that I did not use capital first letter for the new variable.